# assert fact into file in prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I assert a fact into a file without deleting the previous fact?

In the following line, when I execute it twice, the second fact overwrites the first fact:

```
tell('animal.txt'),write(Animal),nl,told.
```

But when I use `assert` or `assertz` it will do nothing.

Help me please.

Thank you :)

Comment: See answer for [Prolog - ASSERT and RETRACT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435237/prolog-assert-and-retract)

Answer (score 0):

`tell` truncates the file you're writing to.

Use [`append('animal.txt')`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append%2f1) instead. That will write to the end of the file.

In reply to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885718/assert-fact-into-file-in-prolog/2887462#2887462):

> Where can I put it?

Do you mean the `append/1`?

Shouldn't the code in your question go in your `type/2` definitions (with append replacing tell)? E.g.

```
type(1, Name) :-
    append('animal.txt'),
    write(mammal(Name)), nl,
    told.
```