# Appending facts into an existing prolog file

Tags: dynamic, prolog, sicstus-prolog, prolog-assert

I'm having trouble inserting facts into an existing Prolog file, without overwriting the original contents.

Suppose I have a file test.pl:

```
:- dynamic born/2. 

born(john,london).
born(tim,manchester).
```

If I load this in prolog, and I assert more facts:

```
| ?- assert(born(laura,kent)).
yes
```

I'm aware I can save this by doing:

```
|?- tell('test.pl'),listing(born/2),told.
```

Which works but test.pl now only contains the facts, not the ":- dynamic born/2":

```
born(john,london).
born(tim,manchester).
born(laura,kent).
```

This is problematic because if I reload this file, I won't be able to insert anymore facts into test.pl because ":- dynamic born/2." doesn't exist anymore.

I read somewhere that, I could do:

```
append('test.pl'),listing(born/2),told.
```

which should just append to the end of the file, however, I get the following error:

```
! Existence error in user:append/1
! procedure user:append/1 does not exist
! goal:  user:append('test.pl')
```

Btw, I'm using Sicstus prolog. Does this make a difference?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should subscribe to answers in question [assert fact into file in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885718/assert-fact-into-file-in-prolog). Or even [Prolog - ASSERT and RETRACT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435237/prolog-assert-and-retract)

Comment: Use `open/3` and `close/1` instead of the outdated `tell`, `told`, `append`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not surprising it only contains the facts as that is all you have told it to save. The easiest way around this is to use

```
|?- tell('test.pl'), write(':- dynamic born/2.'), nl, listing(born/2), told.
```

or write a small procedure which does this. Depending on how you intend to use this you may consider using `save_program/1/2` and `restore/1`.

I can't help you with `append/1` I'm afraid.

Comment: For SWP-Prolog there is no need to `write` declaration of `born/2` directly. It is done by `listing(born/2)`.

Comment: Thanks very much, that certainly does work. I'll take a llook at how I can use save_program and restore.