# Persistence of facts in Prolog

Tags: prolog, persistence

I'm kinda new in Prolog and I'm using SWI-Prolog v6.6 to storage asserts in a `*.pl` file.

```
:- dynamic fact/2.

assert(fact(fact1,fact2)).
```

With the code above I can make asserts and it works fine, but the problem is when I close SWI-Prolog and I open the `*.pl` file again, the asserts I've made are gone...

Is there a way to make asserts and those get stored even if I exit the Prolog process?

Sorry about my bad english and Thanks! (:

Comment: You have to explicitly write them to a file. They are persistent in memory, but when Prolog closes, everything is gone unless written to a file.

Comment: See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921937/appending-facts-into-an-existing-prolog-file, which uses the Edinburgh style I/O.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Saving state has certain [limitations](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=qsavelimits), also see the [recent discussion](https://lists.iai.uni-bonn.de/pipermail/swi-prolog/2014/012776.html) on the SWI-Prolog mailing list.

I think the easiest way to persistently store facts on SWI-Prolog is to use the `persistency` library. For that I would rewrite your code in the following way:

```
:- use_module(library(persistency)).

:- persistent fact(fact1:any, fact2:any).

:- initialization(init).

init:-
  absolute_file_name('fact.db', File, [access(write)]),
  db_attach(File, []).
```

You can now add/remove facts using `assert_fact/2`, `retract_fact/2`, and `retractall_fact/2`.

Upon exiting Prolog the asserted facts are automatically saved to `fact.db`.

Example usage:

```
$ swipl my_facts.pl
?- assert_fact(some(fact), some(other,fact)).
true.
?- halt.
$ swipl my_facts.pl
?- fact(X, Y).
X = some(fact),
Y = some(other, fact).
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you're after is just to get a list of certain facts asserted with a predicate, then mbratch's suggestion will work fine.  But you may also want to save the state of your program in general, in which case you can use `qsave_program/2`. According to the swi docs, `qsave_program(+File, +Options)`

> Saves the current state of the program to the file `File`. The result is a resource archive containing a saved state that expresses all Prolog data from the running program and all user-defined resources.

Documentation here http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=runtime