# Prolog checking if

Tags: if-statement, prolog

I'm creating a text adventure game on SWI-Prolog and I want to include (some kind of) dialogs.

What I have so far is:

```
dialog1(1):- nl,write('blah blah'),nl
             write('a: this is answer a'),nl,
             write('b: this is answer b'),nl.

a:- write('respond to answer a'),nl.
b:- write('respond to answer b'),nl.
```

That's pretty much the first dialog. Now I want to create a second dialog similar to the first one.

```
dialog1(2):- nl,write('blah blah'),nl,
             write('a: this is answer a'),nl,
             write('b: this is answer b'),nl.

a:- write('respond to answer a'),nl.
b:- write('respond to answer b'),nl.
```

How can I check if the dialog is the first or the second one? I want to do that because when the user types `a.`, I need the right answer a to be shown.

I thought I could use something like

```
a(1):- write('respond to answer a'),nl.
b(1):- write('respond to answer b'),nl. 

/* and on the second dialog*/
a(2):- write('respond to answer a'),nl.
b(2):- write('respond to answer b'),nl.
```

But still, if the user is on dialog 2 and he types a(1),the first answer will appear.

Comment: Do you want to create global state like this: `?- dialog(1).` `?- a.` a now shows the answer for dialog 1 an not for dialog 2.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I want to do. On the `dialog(1)` the `a` to show the answer for `dialog(1)` and on `dialog2` the `a` to show the answer for `dialog(2)`

Comment: use `apropos(assert).` for information about `assert(statement)`. with this you can add a new `statement` to the database like `assert(a(1):- write('...'))`. Use `retract` to forget about a statement.

Comment: I can use assert like that? Like give a couple of commands?
`assert(a(1)):- write('aa'),nl,write('qweq').`  ?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435237/prolog-assert-and-retract

Comment: You can do this: `assert(a(1):- write('aa'),nl,write('qweq'))`

Comment: When I run that, I get `true` as a result,but it doesn't write `aa` and `qweq`. and when I run `a(1).` I get `false.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `->` implication as kind of if statement:

```
?- true -> write('t') ; write('f').
t
true.
?- false -> write('t') ; write('f').
f
true.
```

You can `apropos(assert).` for information about `assert(statement)`. With `assert` you can add a new `statements` to the database like `assert(a(1):- write('...'))`. Use `retract` to forget about a statement.

Comment: Like how could I include that in my code?
dialog(1) == true ->  write('t') ; write('f').   ? something like that?

Comment: I am pretty sure that I just did not get the question.. The -> is the if statement but you may need something else.